# Nested sorting - SQL

Tags: sql, sorting, nested, sql-order-by

I have a table like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| ArticleID |ReleaseTime           | PurchaseTime       |
--------------------------------------------------------
|       7   |  7/24/20 3:00 PM     |   NULL             |
--------------------------------------------------------
|       5   |  7/16/20 1:00 PM     |   NULL             | 
---------------------------------------------------------
|       4   |  7/24/20 2:00 PM     |   NULL             |
--------------------------------------------------------
|       1   |         NULL         |   7/25/20 5:45 PM  | 
--------------------------------------------------------
|       3   |         NULL         |   7/26/20 9:00 AM  |
--------------------------------------------------------
|       3   |     7/25/20 8:30 AM  |    NULL            | 
---------------------------------------------------------
|       1   |     7/24/20 5:00 PM  |    NULL            |
--------------------------------------------------------
|       1   |         NULL         |   7/25/20 6:00 PM  | 
---------------------------------------------------------
|       6   |     7/24/20 3:30 PM  |    NULL            |
```

which needs to be sorted by ReleaseTime ASC and then by all PurchaseTime ASC for that ID. Result should look like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| ArticleID |ReleaseTime           | PurchaseTime       |
--------------------------------------------------------
|       5   |  7/16/20 1:00 PM     |   NULL             |
--------------------------------------------------------
|       4   |  7/24/20 2:00 PM     |   NULL             | 
---------------------------------------------------------
|       7   |  7/24/20 3:00 PM     |   NULL             |
--------------------------------------------------------
|       6   |  7/24/20 3:30 PM     |   NULL             | 
--------------------------------------------------------
|       1   |  7/24/20 5:00 PM     |   NULL             |
--------------------------------------------------------
|       1   |         NULL         |   7/25/20 5:45 PM  |
--------------------------------------------------------
|       1   |         NULL         |   7/25/20 6:00 PM  |
--------------------------------------------------------
|       3   |  7/25/20 8:30 AM     |   NULL             | 
---------------------------------------------------------
|       3   |         NULL         |   7/26/20 9:00 AM  |
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which database are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to sort by the minimum release time for each `id` and then sort by purchase time.

You can use a window function in the `order by`:

```
order by min(releasetime) over (partition by id),
         id,
         purchasetime asc
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! Glad you understand it from this non-formatted table (sorry!), this gave me better understanding of "partition by" clause and I was able to apply it on couple of similar problems